# How to hide outdated commits in issue tracker

Tags: github, issue-tracking

If I add an issue number to a commit, it gets shown on the issue tracker on GitHub.

However, if I rebase a branch and push it to GitHub, it not only shows the commits from the current version of the branch, but the now deleted branch.

For example, it shows

> Issue #592 WIP: Generate DataType model         [366d20e](https://github.com/nabu-catalog/nabu/commit/366d20efc0a4dafe1594219b997aeaced13f3767)

and

> Issue #592 WIP: Generate DataType model         [26621a6](https://github.com/nabu-catalog/nabu/commit/26621a6d72cef64d7438703501d74d48404ef2ac)

How can I make GitHub hide the `366d20e` commit?